# CakePHP 3 - use different table aliases when separating JOIN conditions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I'm rebuilding a vanilla PHP/MySQL application using CakePHP 3.5.13.

One of the queries in the original application needs to build a `JOIN` condition on the same table and does so by using separate table aliases. The query is as follows - and gives the correct results that we expect:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(s.id) FROM substances s
JOIN display_substances AS dsUses
ON (s.id = dsUses.substance_id AND dsUses.display_id = 128 AND  (dsUses.value LIKE '%dye%') ) 
JOIN display_substances AS displays
ON (s.id = displays.substance_id AND displays.display_id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,6,128) AND  (displays.value LIKE '%bpr%'))
```

The reason this is needed is because the query is doing a search for 2 separate items of user input - within the same table (`display_substances`) but against different `display_substances .display_id` fields. In terms of the query above it means:

- Search for `"%dye%"` where `display_id = 128`
- Search for `"%bpr%"` where `display_id` is *not* `1,2,3,4,6 or 128`

In Cake I have written it like this in a Controller that handles the search functionality:

```
$query = $Substances->find()->select(['id' => 'Substances.id'])->distinct();

// Search for "dye"
$query = $query->matching('DisplaySubstances', function ($q) use ($uses_summary) {
return $q->where([
        'DisplaySubstances.value LIKE' => '%dye%', // "dye" is dynamic and comes from $uses_summary
        'DisplaySubstances.display_id' => 128
    ]);
});

// Search for "bpr"
$query = $query->matching('DisplaySubstances', function ($q) use ($regulatory_information) {
    return $q->where([
            'DisplaySubstances.value LIKE' => '%bpr%', // "bpr" is dynamic and comes from $regulatory_information
            'DisplaySubstances.display_id NOT IN' => [1,2,3,4,6,128]
        ]);
 });
```

This produces the wrong SQL, because when I debug `$query->sql();` it gives a different `JOIN` condition:

```
INNER JOIN display_substances DisplaySubstances ON 
(
    DisplaySubstances.value like "%dye%" AND DisplaySubstances.display_id = 128 
    AND DisplaySubstances.value like "%bpr%" 
    AND DisplaySubstances.display_id not in (1,2,3,4,6,128) 
    AND Substances.id = (DisplaySubstances.substance_id)
)
```

I'm not sure how to rewrite this query such that it will treat each of the two search inputs as a `JOIN` condition, as per the original query.

The main thing I've noticed is that the original query has separate aliases for the same table (`AS dsUses` and `AS displays`). I'm not sure if this is relevant?

I'm trying to use the ORM as opposed to writing the SQL manually so would prefer to know how to use it to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [**not yet**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/9499) possible to specify custom aliases for `matching()` calls, currently multiple `matching()` calls on the same association will merge the conditions as can be seen in your generated SQL snippet.

For now you'd have to either create additional associations (ie additionally to your `DisplaySubstances` association in your `SubstancesTable` class) with different aliases:

```
$this->hasMany('DsUses', [
    'className' => 'DisplaySubstances'
]);
$this->hasMany('Displays', [
    'className' => 'DisplaySubstances'
]);
```

on which you can then match:

```
$query->matching('DsUses', function ($q) use ($regulatory_information) {
    return $q->where([
        'DsUses.value LIKE' => '%dye%',
        'DsUses.display_id' => 128
    ]);
});

$query->matching('Displays', function ($q) use ($regulatory_information) {
    return $q->where([
        'Displays.value LIKE' => '%bpr%',
        'Displays.display_id NOT IN' => [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 128]
    ]);
});
```

or build the joins manually, for example using `innerJoin()`:

```
$query->innerJoin(
    [
        'DsUses' => 'display_substances'
    ],
    [
        'Substances.id' => new \Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression('DsUses.substance_id'),
        'DsUses.display_id' => 128,
        'DsUses.value LIKE' => '%dye%'
    ],
    [
        'DsUses.display_id' => 'integer',
        'DsUses.value' => 'string'
    ]
);

$query->innerJoin(
    [
        'Displays' => 'display_substances'
    ],
    [
        'Substances.id' => new \Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression('Displays.substance_id'),
        'Displays.display_id NOT IN' => [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 128],
        'Displays.value LIKE' => '%bpr%'
    ],
    [
        'Displays.display_id' => 'integer',
        'Displays.value' => 'string'
    ]
);
```

See also

- **[cakephp/cakephp#9499 : Improve association data fetching](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/9499)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Adding Joins](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)**

Comment: Thanks for this. For clarification please can you add to the answer which Table class the `hasMany` conditions (first option) should go in? I'm guessing it's the `SubstancesTable`? I opted to use the second method of building joins manually because this is a special circumstance in the application and is only used in 1 place.

Comment: @Andy Correct, it would be in the `SubstancesTable`, ie the same table where your `DisplaySubstances` association is defined (I've guessed that it's a `hasMany`, if it's a `hasOne` you'd have to use that accordingly for the new associations, ie they should be identical to the `DisplaySubstances` association).